# How to test compound json object response in a controller within grails 2.4.3

Tags: rest, grails, testing, junit, spock

I am testing the save method of a Restful controller, the `CustomerController`.

The Customer, the domain class, has an Address association, Address has a City, a City has a State, and a State has a Country.

I wrote custom marshallers and a custom binding helper for `Address`, so a JSON Customer is like this:

```
{
    "id": "g2c3e08iqton4v5bsgti33gkpd35l0er",
    "firstName": "Bob1",
    "lastName": "Patiño1",
    "middleName": "The Payaso1",
    "email": "me@bobpatino.org",
    "phoneNumber": "300555551",
    "address": {
        "addressLine1": "addressLine1",
        "postalCode": "110111",
        "city": {
            "name": "Bogotá",
            "state": "DC",
            "country": "CO"
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working using that format, remember the custom marshallers and binding helper for Address, but now I want to test the controller.

```
 @Unroll
 void "create a new customer firstName: #firstName"(){
        when: 'the merchantUser requests to create a new Customer'
        controller.request.method = 'POST'
        controller.request.contentType = JSON_CONTENT_TYPE
        controller.request.JSON = [
            firstName: firstName, lastName : lastName, middleName:middleName,
            gender: gender, email: email, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, address: address
        ]
        controller.save()

        then:'The response code should be CREATED (201)'
        controller.response.status == 201

        and: 'The new customer should be returned'
        controller.response.json.firstName == firstName
        //TODO How to validate the address is added?
        //controller.response.json.address == ????
        1 * controller.springSecurityService.getPrincipal() >> merchantUser

        where:
        firstName|lastName|middleName|gender|email|phoneNumber|address
        JSONObject.NULL     |JSONObject.NULL    |JSONObject.NULL      |JSONObject.NULL  |JSONObject.NULL |JSONObject.NULL|JSONObject.NULL
        'bob'    |'patiño'|'de'      |'M'   |'bob@patino.co'| '20055555'| [ addressLine1 :'addressLine1', postalCode:'110111',city :[name:'Bogotá',state:'DC',country:'CO']]
    }
```

And my controller save methods is

```
@Transactional
    def save() {
        if(handleReadOnly()) {
            return
        }
        def customer = createResource()
        customer.merchant = MerchantUser.findByUsername(springSecurityService.getPrincipal().username)?.merchant
        customer.validate()
        if (customer.hasErrors()) {
            respond customer.errors, [status: UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY] // STATUS CODE 422
            return
        }

        customer.save()

        request.withFormat {
            json {
                respond customer, [status: CREATED] // STATUS CODE 201
            }
        }
    }
```

If I debug the CustomerController, I found the customer resources is created with a valid Address form the send information, in fact if I run the code it works, but when running the test, the **controller.response.json** does not contains the address object.

I also had setup the Mock annotation for Customer and Address.

The problem can also be related to the use of custom marshallers in Unit Tests. The `controller.response.json` is as follows

```
{
    "middleName": "de",
    "id": 1,
    "lastName": "patiño",
    "phoneNumber": "20055555",
    "merchant": {
        "id": 1,
        "class": "models.Merchant"
    },
    "email": "bob@patino.co",
    "address": {
        "id": null,
        "class": "models.Address"
    },
    "customerToken": "21jtdik0m99pnarth8g25meb423fmoh0",
    "lastUpdated": null,
    "gender": "M",
    "dateCreated": null,
    "class": "models.Customer",
    "firstName": "bob"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you're registering your custom JSON marshaller(s) in `BootStrap.groovy`, which is not executed for certain types of tests (the precise rules are unclear to me and not well documented)

One way to avoid this limitation is to use the `ObjectMarshallerRegisterer` approach described here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-goodness-register-custom.html

Comment: Yes, I was registering the custom marshallers in Bootstrap.groovy. I changed to approach described in the article you mention and still have the same problem. It works like a charm when run in development or production, but in the unit test the Address of the response just contains a `{ "id": null }`
I think marshallers did not work, because JSON response is just like unsing the default JSON marshaller.

Comment: I believe you'll need to switch from a unit to an integration test in order for your JSON marshaller to be picked up and used in the (mock) controller response.  Also, one benefit of the `ObjectMarshallerRegisterer` approach is that it greatly simplifies the task of testing your marshallers in isolation (using unit tests, rather than paying the integration test performance penalty)

Comment: You're right. Before seeing your comment I wrote the integration test and is working as it should. Do you think the question is still valid? I think the question still makes senses, because I am not testing the marshallers, but the response content.

Comment: Yes, definitely a valid question.  There are often good reasons to test both your controller responses (using integration tests) and marshallers in isolation (with unit tests).  Both levels of testing become possible when you use `ObjectMarshallerRegisterer` rather than the `BootStrap.groovy` approach.